# Buying and selling the same stock. How is gain for taxes calculated?

Tags: united-states, stocks, capital-gains-tax

Asking from US tax perspective,

- I have a stock that I bought for $1.
- I sell it at some point for $2.
- Within a week or two after, the same stock falls to $1.3. At this point, I buy one stock again.

Is tax calculated on the basis of $0.7 (2 - 1.3, net extra money I ended up with) or $1 (the gain from the first lot)? Does time period between these events make any difference?

Comment: If you had bought both lots before the sale, you get to choose which shares are sold.  If you don't want to do first-in first-out you need to inform your broker which shares to sell, assuming your purchases are recent enough that the broker tracks the basis for you.  Also watch out for a wash sale.  If you lost money on the first purchase and bought the same stock within 30 days you cannot deduct the loss.

Answer (score 11):

You are taxed on *realized* gains. So you would be taxed on the $1 per share profit.  The *next* time you sell, your cost basis would be $1.30.

> Does time period between these events make any difference?

Only when determining if the capital gain is classified as *short-term* or *long-term*. If the sale is more than a year after the purchase, the gain is classified as long-term and taxed at a different rate.

Answer (score 5):

You have a capital gain of $1. Your basis for the new share of stock is $1.30. Because you sold at a gain, there is no adjustment to the basis of the new share. If you had sold at a loss, it would have been added to the basis of the new share. The time period involved is 30 days before, and 30 days after, selling at a loss.

Comment: The situation when selling at a loss and purchasing within 30 days is called a "wash sale".